# Make background color of sitecore form configurable from sitecore

Tags: sitecore-forms, mvc-forms

I am using Sitecore MVC form in rendering and the requirement is to make user capable of changing form back ground.
Need suggestions to achieve it.

1. Can we use rendering param in Sitecore form?
2. Can we create a custom MVC form? I created but it seems to be not working.
3. Or any other ways to achieve it ??

Version: Sitecore 9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- create a new folder under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Meta Data/CSS Class Options` and call it `Form`
- add new items for every color you want to use for the background colors under `Form` folder using `/sitecore/templates/System/Forms/Meta Data/CSS Class Option` template and for the value field use e.g. `form-blue-background`, 'form-grey-background`, etc.:
  [image]
- select `/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Field Types/Form` item and in `Css Class Autocomplete Options` field select `/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Meta Data/CSS Class Options/Form` folder created earlier:
  [image]
- now when your content authors start typing first name of the CSS class in `CSS Class` field of `Styling` section in `Forms Editor`, there will be auto-suggested option for all the available styles that you define:

[image]

Remember to add proper styling in your CSS files for all the background options.

---

**EDIT**

In Sitecore 9.2 there is no option for CSS Class Options metadata, but your content authors can still add any CSS class to the `Styling` section in Form Editor:
[image]

There is no way to add auto-suggestion for the classes so you need to inform them about all the possible options for form backgrounds.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Marek for the detailed reply. However, the suggested items are not available in SC9.2.

"/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Meta Data/CSS Class Options"
"/sitecore/templates/System/Forms/Meta Data/CSS Class Option"

In SC10, I can see items. How to do this in SC9.2 ?

Comment: @RashmiRanjan answer updated. In Sitecore 9.2 there is no option for CSS Class Options metadata, but your content authors can still add any CSS class to the `Styling` section in Form Editor. There is no way to add auto-suggestion for the classes so you need to inform them about all the possible options for form backgrounds.

Comment: Got it. Thanks @Marek.